# how to check function is called or not in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I am trying to test `component` in angular .following thing I need to test

1. service function is called or not
2. how to mock the response

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-w9towo?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

**spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture,TestBed, async,getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture:ComponentFixture<AppComponent>,
      component:AppComponent,
      injector:TestBed,
      service:AppService,
      httpMock:HttpTestingController,
      el:HTMLElement;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [ AppService ]

    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
  //httpMock.verify();
});
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
   // injector = getTestBed();
   // service = injector.get(AppService);
   // httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);

    spyOn('appService',getData);


  describe('AppComponent onit test', () => {
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }));
  it('should called appService getData method', async(() => {
    expect(appService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
})
});
```

**getting error** 
**cannot read property 'injector' of null**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can mock the service that way:

```
const mockPosts: Posts = {
   userId: 10,
   id: 10,
   title: "post",
   body: "post"};

class MockAppService extends AppService{

   public getData() {
      return Observable.of(mockPosts)
   }
  }
```

and use that mock class in your providers instead of the service

```
 { provide: AppService, useClass: MockAppService },
```

and add this:

```
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 appservice = TestBed.get(AppService); // this line
```

you can spyOn that service and return a value like this

```
spyOn(appservice , 'getData').and.returnValue("your value")
```

final file

```
   import { ComponentFixture,TestBed, async,getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
  import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
  import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { AppService } from './app.service';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import { Posts } from './post.interface';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

  const mockPosts: Posts = 
  {userId: 10,
  id: 10,
  title: "post",
  body: "post",};
 class MockAppService extends AppService {
 public getData(){
    return Observable.of(mockPosts)
   }
 }

 describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture:ComponentFixture<AppComponent>,
  component:AppComponent,
  injector:TestBed,
  service:AppService,
  httpMock:HttpTestingController,
  el:HTMLElement;
 beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
   ],
   providers: [ 
    { provide: AppService, useClass: MockAppService }
   ]

   }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(AppService)
    // injector = getTestBed();
    // service = injector.get(AppService);
    // httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    spyOn(service,'getData');
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
  //httpMock.verify();
  });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  service = TestBed.get(AppService)
  // injector = getTestBed();
  // service = injector.get(AppService);
  // httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);

  spyOn(service,'getData');


  describe('AppComponent onit test', () => {
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }));
  it('should called appService getData method', async(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges(); 
     expect(service.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
  })
 });
```

Comment: i don't know why i'm not able to share it but i updated the answer with the final file, check it

Comment: still I am getting error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-w9towo?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: could you please look once again

Comment: i've edited the answer , you have to put this code inside beforeeach after compiling , fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      service = TestBed.get(AppService)
      // injector = getTestBed();
      // service = injector.get(AppService);
      // httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);

      spyOn(service,'getData');

Comment: i've added import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; and i added fixture.detectChanges() here,  it('should called appService getData method', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(service.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

Comment: now you have this error: Failed: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays, because user is not an array, to to change it and your test will work perfectly

Comment: change your mockPosts to an array by adding [] and the method getData of AppService to  public getData(): Observable<Posts[]> {
    return this.http.get<Posts[]>