# How to mock an @injected service when testing an angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

I have a component with the signature:

```
constructor(private loremApiService: LoremApiService,
      private ipsumService: IpsumService,
      private dolorService: DolorService,
      @Inject('sitService') private sitService: library.service.Service) {
}
```

The spec file for the component is set up with:

```
let component: PowerBiReportComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestingComponent>;
const mockLoremApi = { methodThatIsCalled: () => {} };
const mockIpsumService = { };
const mockSitService = { };

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ TestingComponent ],
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
        providers: [
            { provide: LoremApiService, useValue: mockLoremApi },
            { provide: IpsumService, useValue: mockIpsumService },
            UnmockedService,
            { provide: library.service.Service, useValue: mockSitService }
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

However, the provider is not used, due to the @Inject decorator, the test is failing on run with:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[sitService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[sitService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for sitService!
```

How do I force the TestingModule to use the mockSitService despite it being @Injected in the component?

Comment: Did you try to do: `{ provide: 'sitService', useValue: mockSitService }`?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Unfortunately the unanonymised service is imported with `import * as library from 'sit-library';`, so I can't be that specific. Also, tragically, the actual service Type is named `Service`

Comment: Whatever is in the `@Inject(...)` should be what is given as the `provide` property. Newer versions of Angular require (or strongly recommends?) these to be injection tokens https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Ahhh, I've changed the provide object in the test to match the injectionToken in the component's parent module. Now it's erroring with an `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` which may be part of the actual test code failing due to an unimplemented mock. This might fix the issue

Comment: check my response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49842183/4399281 you can find an example of mocking a service

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel If you add ensuring that the injection tokens match in the component's module and the TestModule as the configureTestingModule as an answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the comments, Angular needs whatever token is in the `@Inject(...)` to be the same as what is given for the `provide` property when setting up the service with Angular's DI. This also means that the injection token should be exported outside the module for others to use the `@Inject()` syntax.

If the service is provided like this:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: SERVICE_TOKEN, useClass: Service }
    ]
})
```

Then the `@Inject()` should be set up like this (using the same injection token):

```
constructor(@Inject(SERVICE_TOKEN) private service: Service) {
}
```

So, in your test you mock it out via (again, using the same injection token):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: SOME_TOKEN, useValue: mockService }
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

For more information on injection tokens, refer to the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken).

Comment: What if you have a module, that uses `forRoot` for it's injectable tokens and you want to test one of the services inside of it that utilizes the injected token? `MyModule.forRoot(MyModuleConstants)` has a service `MyModuleService` and has `constructor(@Inject(MyInjectionToken) constants)`

Comment: `useClass` instead of `useValue`?

Comment: @GaoShenghan the syntax depends on what you are providing. When setting it up in the module it is using `useClass` so that Angular creates the instance for you. In the test, the OP has variables that are instances of the stubbed services, so you would use the `useValue` version of the provide syntax for those.