# how to write unity tests for the AuthService class registration method

Tags: angular, unity-game-engine

how to write unity tests for the AuthService class registration method

**my code AuthService class:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {
    // ...
  }

  registration(newUser) {

    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('/register', JSON.stringify(newUser), options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  } 

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

How to run the auth.service.spec.ts file?

**script code auth.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('AuthService', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let serviceTest: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [AuthService]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    serviceTest = TestBed.get(AuthService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
  });

   it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }));

  it('should be created', inject([AuthService], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

How to test the registration method?

command:

```
 ng test --port 4200
```

causes errors:

```
ERROR in d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'd:\name_projectnode_modules\selenium-webdriver\net'
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 22:15-39
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./auth.service.spec.ts
 @ .. \.spec\.ts$
 @ ../test.ts

ERROR in d:/name_project/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'd:\name_projectnode_modules\fs.realpath'
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js 8:9-22
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
 @ d:/name_project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./auth.service.spec.ts
 @ .. \.spec\.ts$
 @ ../test.ts
```

how to fix the above errors?

I made the coomand:
`npm i selenium-webdriver --save-dev`

but it still returns the same errors

Comment: check my answer here bro https://stackoverflow.com/a/49842183/4399281 you can find how to mock the service and override it's method and how you can spyOn that method and check if its called

Comment: how to test this **auth.service.spec.ts** script from the command line? Command: `d:\name_project\src\app>ng test auth.service.spec.ts --port 4200` returns errors

Comment: replace it with fit in your test like this fit('should be ...', () => { ...}) so when you run ng test, only the test with fit with excute and not the others

Comment: I improved the post. I did the `ng test --port 4200` command but it still returns errors. How to correct errors?

Comment: my project not have the file `webpack.config.js`

Comment: add to the file `package.json` : `"browser": {
    "child_process": false
  }
}` but it did not help, there are still the same errors